# The following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty):

Tags: flutter, mobile

I'm trying to load my flutter app but I'm getting the error below. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

`EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY    the following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty):   Null check operator used on a null value`

here is my code for main.dart

```
 void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
      ),
      title: 'lateh',
      initialRoute: BuzmeRoutes.profilePage,
      routes: BuzmeRoutes.routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working with following way of setting the routes. Please recheck whether you have set the routes in a correct way inside Buzmeroutes.routes:

```
initialRoute: '/profile',
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
      '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
    },
```